# Question on coefficients of products of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let us have two univariate polynomials $P\left({x}\right)$ and $Q\left({x}\right)$, both with integer coefficients, such that

1. the sum of the coefficients of $P\left({x}\right)$ is equal to 1.
2. $P\left({x}\right)$ has at least one negative coefficient.

Could it be proved that $R\left({x}\right)=P\left({x}\right)Q\left({x}\right)$ has at least one negative coefficient, or otherwise could you give me some counterexample?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

As a counterexample has been given, but $R\left({x}\right)$ has some coefficients equal to zero, would it be possible a counterexample with the condition of $R\left({x}\right)$ not having coefficients equal to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(X^2-X+1)(X^2+X+1)=X^4+X^2+1
$$

Comment: Thanks @ancientmathematician!